# PHP Notice: Undefined variable: conn in C:\Users\lucas\php_Server\DB\manager.php on line 7

Tags: php, postgresql

estou com um problema para conectar no banco de dados, mais especifico para registrar um valor

eu tentei fazer a conexão aqui

```
class DBConnection{

        private $conn;

            function __construct(){
                $this->conn = pg_connect("host='localhost' port='5432' dbname='desafio_softexpert' user='postgres' password='****'") or die("cannot connect to DB");
            }
            public function get_conn(){
                return $this->conn;
            }
    }
```

e aqui queria que a variavel conn recebece o retorno da conexão, mas da um erro

```
include("./DB/DBConnection.php");
    $DBConnection = new DBConnection();
    $conn = $DBConnection->get_conn();

    function insert_in_DB($query){
        $result = pg_query ($conn, $query);
        if (!$result)
            echo "query did not execute";
        $rs = pg_fetch_assoc($result);
        if (!$rs)
          echo "0 records";
```

Comment: você acabou esquecendo de colocar public na function de construção mesmo..

<?php

class DBConnection {
    private $conn;
    public function __construct() { ... 

se você fizer dessa forma irá funcionar normal.

no erro diz que a variável está undefined ou seja sem definição

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu código está apresentando erro pois a variável $conn não está disponível no escopo da função na qual está sendo utilizada.

Para que o código funcione corretamente, basta realizar a seguinte alteração

```
include("./DB/DBConnection.php");
$DBConnection = new DBConnection();
$conn = $DBConnection->get_conn();

function insert_in_DB($query) use ($conn){
    $result = pg_query ($conn, $query);
    if (!$result)
        echo "query did not execute";
    $rs = pg_fetch_assoc($result);
    if (!$rs)
      echo "0 records";
```

Por padrão no PHP, uma função não tem acesso as variáveis que estão fora do escopo da mesma.

A expressão 'use' indica que você irá utilizar a variável $conn do escopo acima.

Answer (score -1):

O erro foi ocasionado por uma falha na sua escrita de código, você eventualmente acabou se esquecendo de colocar public na função de construção e a variável usada em getConn está com valor não definido por isso ocasionou o erro, se você corrigir assim como mostro abaixo você terá o problema solucionado.

```
<?php 
class DBConnection {
   private $conn;

   public function __construct() {
      $this->conn = pg_connect("host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=desafio_softexpert;user=postgres;password=****") or die("cannot connect to DB");
   }
}
```

Comment: Quando você não adiciona os modificadores de acesso em métodos, o PHP parte do principio de que os mesmos são públicos, sendo assim, essa alteração não resolveria o problema do Lucas.